# Convert UTC timezone into AWST timezone in ZF2

Tags: php, date, datetime, zend-framework2, timezone

I am trying to convert the timezone with below piece of code which is working fine except AWST timezone.

```
$date = time();
$timeZone = "AWST";
$dt = new \DateTime();
$dt->setTimestamp($date);
$dt->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone($timeZone));
echo  $dt->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

If i put $timeZone = "UTC" or something that is working fine. Experts can help me out from this.

Comment: So what happens with the code you've already got?

Comment: This is the issue I am getting => PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone (AWST)'

Comment: Right. I suggest you add that to the question, and in future please include all relevant information when you ask a question.

Comment: Try `$dt = new \DateTime("@$date"); $dt->setTimezone(new \DateTimezone('Australia/Perth')); echo $dt->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');`. See [demo](https://eval.in/295977).

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem is that you need to specify an [IANA](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) [time zone ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) rather than just an abbreviation. Time zone abbreviations are *really* problematic for various reasons:

- They usually indicate "half" a time zone; "Europe/London" switches between "GMT" and "BST" for example
- They can be ambiguous - for example, "CST" means different things in different places (and at different points in history)
- Different places switch between different abbreviations at different times of year.

If you can get the right time zone ID for the place you care about, that should give you the right local time throughout history, assuming the time zone data is complete and accurate.

In your case, I believe you want the Australia/Perth time zone. Try this:

```
$timeZone = "Australia/Perth"
```